# How to generate a permutation without two adjacent consecutive numbers?

Tags: c++

In this problem, we will say that a permutation is cool is it does not have two adjacent consecutive numbers. Given n, print all the cool permutations of {0, …, n − 1}.
Input
input consists of several cases, each with an n between 1 and 9.
Output
For every case, print in lexicographical order all the cool permutations of {0, …, n − 1}.

I know how to solve the problem that prints all the permutations of { 1, …, n-1 } in lexicographical order. But I do not know how to generate the permutations without two adjacent consecutive numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void write(const vector<int>& v) {
    int s = v.size()-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) cout << v[i] << ' ';
    cout << v[s] << endl;
}

void generate(vector<int>& v, vector<bool>& u, int i, int n) {
    if (i == n) write(v);
    else {
        for (int s = 1; s <= n; ++s) {
            if (not u[s]) {
                v[i] = s;
                u[s] = true;
                generate(v, u, i+1, n);
                u[s] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int n;
    while (cin >> n) {
        vector<int> v(n);
        vector<bool> u(n, false);
        generate(v, u, 0, n-1);
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

With this input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I expect this output:

```
0



1 3 0 2
2 0 3 1

0 2 4 1 3
0 3 1 4 2
1 3 0 2 4
1 3 0 4 2
1 4 2 0 3
2 0 3 1 4
2 0 4 1 3
2 4 0 3 1
2 4 1 3 0
3 0 2 4 1
3 1 4 0 2
3 1 4 2 0
4 1 3 0 2
4 2 0 3 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: idea: write a `bool is_cool(Permutation)` function, print a permutation only if it `is_cool`.

Comment: other idea: with the [right tool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), listing all permutations takes less than a dozen lines.

Answer (score 0):

An inefficient way of generating cool permutations, would be to first generate all permutations, and then to create a method that takes the vector `v` (who stores a candidate permutation), and evaluate whether this permutation is cool or not. If yes, print, if no, skip it, as @YSC suggested.

Example:

```
bool isCool(const vector<int>& v)
{
  // special case, v.size==2
  if(v.size() == 2) {
    if(v[0] == v[1] + 1 || v[0] == v[1] - 1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  // start from second element to pre-last
  // and check if prev and next are adjacent to it
  for(size_t i = 1; i < v.size() - 1; ++i) { 
    if(v[i] == v[i - 1] + 1 || v[i] == v[i - 1] - 1 ||
          v[i] == v[i + 1] + 1 || v[i] == v[i + 1] - 1)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and then you would use it like in your generate method:

```
if (i == n && isCool(v)) write(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool ConsecValues(int x, int y)
{
    return abs(x - y) == 1;
}

bool HasConsecAdjValues(const vector<int>& v)
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator cIter = adjacent_find(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 
        ConsecValues);
    return cIter != v.end();
}

vector<vector<int>> GetCoolPerms(int n)
{
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    vector<int> v(n);
    iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

    do {
        if (!HasConsecAdjValues(v))
            result.push_back(v);
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));

    return result;
}

void PrintPerm(const vector<int>& v)
{
    for (const auto& num : v)
        cout << num;

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> coolPerms = GetCoolPerms(5);

    for (const auto& perm : coolPerms)
        PrintPerm(perm);

    getchar();
}
```